# Most reliable method for ASP.Net to Classic ASP 3Des/Aes Encryption

Tags: asp.net, encryption, asp-classic

i was reviewing some other posts here and found some options that I have done some research on, but haven't quite found the information i'm looking for, such as reliability and its request capacity and speed, etc.

So far i've found 3 possible methods of (3DES/AES) encryption for ASP.Net/Classic ASP compatibility are:

**1.Capicom.DLL**

But how much work is involved when using the .Net app, I've heard it places extra variables in the encrypted data, so it makes the process a bit more troublesome in .Net.
It is distributed by Microsoft, but how well can this function operate under heavy workloads?

**2.Chillkat**

Third party component, never tried it, and don't know how well it can handle large workloads.  I have used a third-party one before, and it has just crashed out when the workload got too heavy on the server.

**3.ASP.Net web service using .Net library**

Use HTTPRequests from classic asp to get the data.  This is a possibility, but i'm just thinking something that was internal, like a DLL, would be quicker and more efficient/reliable?

Any help with this would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ASP.NET C#, there's an existing namespace which you can call that does the security stuffs for you.

[System.Security.Cryptography Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aspx)

Comment: Now how about when i'm in the classic ASP application?

Comment: I have not done any encryption stuff in classic ASP / VB Script so don't know the answer :(